# How to configure the CORS policy in Amazon S3 to upload documents from React App?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I am sending this message here because I want to clarify some questions about a backend solution that I am developing on AWS. Actually, I have 1 question that I would really like you to answer me :)

So, I configured S3 bucket with public access in order to be able to upload files from a front react application. However, even having configured the CORS policy to allow all origins, I get a `No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource` error in my browser.
The CORS policy I applied to my S3 bucket is in the following picture:

[image: CORS policy screenshot]

I tried to solve the problem by recreating other strategies and even by recreating another bucket ... I ended up letting go.

But the strangest thing is that a day later, without me having touched anything, the original CORS error has disappeared, and now I can upload my files in the S3 bucket normally.

Why it didn't work before and why it started to work on its own?

Comment: Picture is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything setup correctly then it works as it is, your question does not have full information or any clues to investigate and understand the problem.

An example of Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) to reference which restrict permission to your domain only as the best practice.

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "HEAD",
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://*.cloudopz.co"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "ETag"
        ]
    },
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "HEAD",
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://*.cloudopz.co"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "ETag"
        ]
    }
]
```